# Responsive response of SAPUI5 components doesn't work when redimensionning component

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, sapui5

### Environment :

Framework : SAPUI5 V1.38
IDE : SAP WEB IDE

### Problem :

When I am changing the size the whole windows the grid component works fine and one go under the other when to small, however when I am redimensionnement the parent component and not the window the grid component doesn't wrap anymore which is strange (I am trying to do a preview for a set of devices like in google chrome debugger).

### Screenshot :

Full screen window : 
[image: Full screen windows]
Manually resized window : 
[image: resized window]
Resized by component :
[image: resized by component]

Code :
in the view for the grid part

```xml
<content>
<FlexBox id="globalFlex" direction="Column">
    <l:VerticalLayout width="{previewModel>/ScreenWidth}" id="emulatedView">
    <!--some code-->
        <l:Grid>
            <VBox>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L3 M12 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="some.fragment" type="XML"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L9 M12 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="some.fragment" type="XML"/>
            </VBox>
        </l:Grid>
        <!--some code-->
    </l:VerticalLayout>
</FlexBox>
</content>
```

for the view of the VerticalLayout size definition :

```xml
<Label labelFor="deviceType" text="{i18n>deviceType}"/>
<RadioButtonGroup id="deviceType" select="onSelectDevice">
    <RadioButton id="desktop" text="{i18n>desktop}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="1264px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="100%"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="amazonTablet" text="{i18n>KindleFireHDX}">
        <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="width" value="800px"/>
        <core:CustomData key="height" value="1280px"/>
    </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosTablet" text="{i18n>ipad}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="768px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="1024px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosTabletPro" text="{i18n>ipadpro}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="1024px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="1366px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="androidPhoneS" text="{i18n>phoneG4S5}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="360px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="640px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="androidPhoneM" text="{i18n>phonePixel2}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="411px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="731px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="androidPhoneL" text="{i18n>phonePixel2XL}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="411px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="823px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosPhoneOld" text="{i18n>iphoneSE}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="320px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="568px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosPhoneBasic" text="{i18n>iphone}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="375px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="667px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosPhonePlus" text="{i18n>iphonePlus}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="414px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="736px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton id="iosPhoneX" text="{i18n>iphoneX}">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="width" value="375px"/>
            <core:CustomData key="height" value="812px"/>
        </customData>
    </RadioButton>
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

and the controller dealing with it :

```
onSelectDevice: function(oEvt) {
    this.getView().byId("globalFlex").setAlignItems("Center"); 
    var oDimentions = oEvt.getSource().getSelectedButton().getCustomData();
    this.getView().getModel("previewModel").setProperty("/ScreenWidth", oDimentions[0].getValue());
}
```

for fast information the first action in the controller is to center the global flexbox you see in the XML i post for the grid.
the second action is to get the custom data from the radio button that you can see in the second XML fragment I post.
the last action is to set the width in the model that is read by the vertical layout you can see in the first XML fragment.

Comment: Your "resized window" (second screenshot) is still huge. Are you sure it's rendered properly if you resize it to a phone?

Comment: It look fine with chrome debugger for phone, I probably resize the whole window (manully) at the M breakpoint at the screenshot to show the problem of wrapping when i use the coding method (with radio button and component resize)